# XML column update in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

How can I update certain rows in a XML column?

```
UPDATE dbo.tablename 
SET col_name.modify('replace value of (/ArrayOfPromotionRuleBase/PromotionRuleBase/ExpirationDate/text())[1] with ("2017-01-03")')
```

How can I use the below `where` clause in the above query? It should only apply for the codes I use in the where clause.

```
WHERE code LIKE 'XYZ123'
```

xml code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6Q0d.png)

Comment: Can you please show us the XML content - one or two samples?

Comment: Could you specify what is *code* ? Is it xml colum, xml attribute, column?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/S6Q0d.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one worked for me.Thanks

`UPDATE DBO.tablename
SET col_name.modify('replace value of 
(/ArrayOfPromotionRuleBase/PromotionRuleBase/ExpirationDate/text())[1] with ("2017-01-03T00:00:00")') WHERE code IN  ('XYZ','ABC','123')`